# Is it possible to have the load cell signal as feedback to the servo drive of the servo motor?

Tags: motors, linear-motion, servo, linear-motors

In my project, I have to control the linear motion in one of the two modes. It will  be either in position control or load control.

for the displacement control, The servo motor takes the quadrature encoder input as a feedback signal to control the displacement and getting the very accurate displacement control.

Same way, for the load control mode, I want to control the motor, based on the load cell signal as a feedback input. I could not find a possibility of to do so without having an intermediate controller.

In a servo drive, there is a torque mode control mode. But there is no feedback input in the drive. In this case, I think, the servo drive is controlling the motor torque may be through the current consumption of the motor. Rather, is it possible to control the motor based on load cell signal as a feedback input? If there is a solution to connect load cell input for the torque control, then intermediate controller for load control can be avoided.

Comment: You can design that the motor is controlled from the feedback from any sensor.

Comment: Servo motor and drive cannot accept the feedback signal from any sensor.